# How to create a hover directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to make a simple hover directive, how do i persist my "$scope.selected" variable? Because, when i click in one link and after that click in another, the link before still marked... I've seen many other posts about this, but none of them use "partial" or directives.

my html:

```
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <rf-hover rf-on-hover-class="hover" rf-on-hover-index="0" ng-transclude>Home</rf-hover>
        <rf-hover rf-on-hover-class="hover" rf-on-hover-index="1" ng-transclude>About us</rf-hover>
        <rf-hover rf-on-hover-class="hover" rf-on-hover-index="2" ng-transclude>Contact</rf-hover>
      </ul>
    </nav>
```

my angularjs directive:

```
app.directive('rfHover', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
          onHoverClass: '@rfOnHoverClass',
          index: '@rfOnHoverIndex'
        },
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        templateUrl: "partial.html",
        controller: function ($scope) {
            $scope.selected = null;
            $scope.clicked  = false;

            $scope.mouseover = function () {
              $scope.selected = $scope.index;
            };

            $scope.mouseleave = function () {
              if($scope.clicked !== $scope.index) {
                $scope.selected = false;
              }
            }

            $scope.mouseclick = function () {
              $scope.selected = $scope.index;
              $scope.clicked  = $scope.index;
            }

            $scope.isSelected = function () {
                return  $scope.selected === $scope.index 
            };
        }
    };
});
```

my partial html element:

```
<li ng-mouseover='mouseover()' ng-mouseleave="mouseleave()" ng-click="mouseclick()"
ng-class="{active : isSelected()}"></li>
```

and [plnkr.co](http://plnkr.co/edit/4aPxfSM1g9T8Ao1GhxTA?p=preview)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - what is the issue that you are trying to solve?

Comment: when you click in one li, it receive a class(active), but after that, when you click in another, the li before must remove the class(active) and the current li receive the class(active), but that's is not what happens.

Comment: So you want the items to become red on mouseover and return to normal on mouseout. And if you click any item it stays red until you click another item, then this one should return to normal and that other should become red. Is this correct ?

Comment: yes Igor, you are correct! and understand better how this scope works...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, I think you're over-complicating your life here. You can achieve what you want by using the built-in directives and he right CSS. no need to build your own directive.

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li ng-click="select.i=link" ng-repeat="link in links" ng-class="{active: select.i===link}">{{link}}</li>
</ul>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.links=["Home", "About", "Contact Us"];
$scope.select={};
```

Note: `$scope.select` is an object to ensure its passed by reference.

**CSS**

```
li {
   cursor: pointer; 
}

li.active, li:hover{
  color: red;
}
```

See http://plnkr.co/edit/mIcrzJv2qjjaTFCNNMDK?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

Well one big issue you have is that you're using three separate directives, each with their own isolate scopes. Your directives have no way of communicating with each other. The `$scope.selected` is different for each.

My advice would be to make one directive with creates your `ul` with `li` that way you can deal with one scope that stores your selected value.

AN alternative would be to store `$scope.selected` inside a parent controller and use `scope: {selected: "="}` in your directive.

Comment: please, see my http://plnkr.co/edit/4aPxfSM1g9T8Ao1GhxTA?p=preview, how would i use my parent controller?

Comment: that's a parent directive, not controller. See http://plnkr.co/edit/8DiJn8PC8tKnTfaMgNLy?p=preview the logic still needs to be improved obviously but at least you have one selected.

Comment: also, why not just attach a hover CSS class, no need to do angular here, especially because your logic doesn't really work. (`$scope.selected` can only hold 1 value but you possibly want more that one item to be selected a a time, that can't work)

Comment: it's working now: http://plnkr.co/edit/4aPxfSM1g9T8Ao1GhxTA?p=preview, i can't just use hover in css, because it's more complicate than just use it.

Comment: Up to you how you want to organize your code but my solution is significantly less code.

Comment: do you thing that just css hover can handle that? It's not a link and it's more complicate, i would need more than hover attribute.

Comment: If all you want to do on hover in change the style then the CSS class is definitely enough. If you want to do more (e.g. DOM manipulation) on hover, then you can always do that on top of your hover class, kinda like you started doing.